# Помогите переписать код (Python)

Tags: python, list, циклы

Язык: Python
Мне нужно подсчитать кол-во символов, в каждом элементе списка.
Я написал код:

```
a=input().split()
a[0]="new"
b=list(map(lambda x: len(x), a))
print(b)
```

Но мне нужен такой же результат при помощи циклов. Как это сделать несовсем понимаю.

Comment: т.е. лямбду и map умеешь, а намного более простые циклы - нет. Может, и код не ты написал?

Comment: Я пропустил циклы. А теперь не могу их понять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
a=input().split()
flag = 0
result = list()
for word in a:
    for letter in word:
        flag += 1
    result.append(flag)
    flag = 0
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input().split() #ввод элементов через пробел
a[0] = "new" #не знаю зачем
b = list() #список в который будет помещен результат
for i in a: #проходимся циклом по списку a
    b.append(len(i)) #добавляем длину кадого элемента в список b
print(b) # вывод результата
```

Comment: Только пустой вызов `list()` обычно не используют, используют просто пустой список `[]`

Comment: @CrazyElf некоторые даже забывают про `list()` :) а скобки использовать реально лучше, это не только экономия нажатых клавиш, но и разница в миллионах доли секунд

Comment: @Ovsenka Если потаймить без другого кода эти варианты, то `list()` будет в 4 раза медленнее, чем `[]`. Потому что функцию нужно найти по имени и вызвать, а `[]` - вещь строго определённая, её резолвить не нужно )

Comment: @CrazyElf вы замеряли? Что в 4 раза

Comment: @Ovsenka Да, это легко в любом варианте `ipython` (например, в `Jupyter Notebook`): `%timeit list()` и `%timeit []` и сравниваете время.

Comment: Я видел замеры на больших размерах списка,`list()` медленнее, но не в 4 раза было. Поэтому и спрашиваю как так..

Comment: @Ovsenka Я именно про пустые списки. Понятно, что чем больше сам список, тем разница будет меньше на фоне остальных накладных расходов.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо :)